# Linking failed due to missmatched data types

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to create a report in Crystal Reports 2013 using an Oracle database. At issue is two tables.fields same data different data types.  This is causing the linking to fail. work.job is char(50 byte) while job.id is varchar2 (3 byte), I want to link these two fields so I can pull the job.desc onto the report. I don't have access the database to create views or stored procedures, and even if I it would be local and could not be delivered to the client. I thought I could use the Add Command function in Database Expert but I'm not sure how to use it?  Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution that I can think of in this case is to use sub reports as your data types are not matching.

Take one table in main report and second in sub report inside the main report.

Design your report in sub report and pass the work.job to sub report there write a condition in record selection formula to plink both and by that retrieve field you require from database

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'm sorry it's taken so long for me to reply.  You were exactly right, I solved the problem by creating a formula to convert to same type and linking on the formula.  Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Create an SQL command and use cast to convert the data type to match the datatype of the other table. Then you can link on the resulting field.

```
Select *, CAST(table.Fieldtoconvert AS char(1)) AS newfieldname
From table
```